# Firebase web client upload JSON to Cloud Storage

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I am using the Firebase web client and would like to upload JSON to Cloud Storage. I can create a reference using `firebase.storage().ref().child("/testing.json");`, however I am not sure how to upload the JSON string. The docs only mention uploading files, blobs, and base64 encoded strings.
For example, how do I finish the below to upload to the JSON string to cloud storage, to be stored as a JSON file with "application/json" content type?

```js
const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child("/testing.json");
const jsonString = JSON.stringify({ hello: "world" });
ref.put() // ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storage ref put can take a Blob parameter.  Convert the string to a blob...

```
const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child("/testing.json");
const jsonString = JSON.stringify({ hello: "world" });

const blob = new Blob([jsonString], { type: 'application/json' });
ref.put(blob).then( ... )
```